# Reporting to IProgress from multiple threads returns messages in wrong order

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress

I am wondering, how to use the Progress class from multiple threads, so that the reports order does not get messed up and that the reports would actually go in regular intervals. I do have the following code:

```
int finished = 0;
object finLocker = new object();

try
{
    Parallel.For(0, size, (int step) => {
        //DO STUFF
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        lock (finLocker)
        {
            finished++;
            if (finished % 5000000 == 0)
            {
                progress.Report($"Progress report { (int)(100 * ((double)finished / (double)size)) }%");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

progress is then defined as:

```
IProgress<String> progress = new Progress<String>((String s) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine(s);
});
```

The problem is, that most of the time, I first get 17%, then there is a ~2 sec long delay, and then 34%, 52%, 69% and 87% come in the same time and in wrong order.

I think that the problem is that even though progress.Report is called correctly, the main thread, managing the printing is being paused most of the time (which is not really a bad thing, as it does nothing while the For loop is being executed) - but at the same time it makes the Progress unusable. Is there any way to fix this, preferably without getting rid of the Progress class and moving the printing in the For loop?

Comment: Use [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) for coordination.

Comment: Tried it, works much much worse - it takes ~2x as long to complete the whole operation, all of the messages are printed at the end at the same time, they are still in the wrong order. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: What `SynchronizationContext` are you use?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. I have ideas, but I don't know how you've implemented your code so I'm not comfortable sharing.

Comment: What is the application type? Win Forms? Are you running this code in the click handler of a button? What is the value of the `size` variable?